# elastic search bool query errors

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to run an elasticsearch query defined like so:

```
query = {   
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {"term": {"a": "a1"}},
                {"term": {"b": "b1"}},
                {"term": {"c": "c1"}}       
            ], 
        },
    },
}

es.search("my_index", body=q1)
```

But I get the following error:

```
RequestError: TransportError(400, 'search_phase_execution_exception',         
'failed to create query:
...
```

What's the problem with the query?

Answer (score 1):

Try with this :-

```
{   
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {"term": {"a": "a1"}},
                {"term": {"b": "b1"}},
                {"term": {"c": "c1"}}    
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be failing to parse the JSON since you have a trailing comma in your array. (and a couple more after each of your query and bool properties) The JSON spec does not allow for superfluous trailing commas.